# Hibernate command very important security problem

Tags: debian, security, password, hibernate

I use Debian 9 and use hibernate command very much.

Recently I give attention to how it is working and understand after I turn on PC and hibernate was restoring images and wakes up, it does not ask me for password and directly goes to last screen and tty (Active user session).

I think it is very important security problem, because may other people turn on PC after hibernate, and they get active session access!

I run hibernate command with following syntax:

```
sudo hibernate
```

**How can I get hibernate, to lock PC before it hibernates?**

Comment: Have you enabled the system setting to ask for password after the screen wakes from sleep? Hibernation and Suspend should behave the same and require login.

Comment: It sounds like you're not using whole-drive encryption, so even if there were a password prompt, it would be trivially bypassed. If you're really concerned about this, you need to enable that as well as fixing this.

Comment: @Sir_Scofferoff yes its turned on by default and when screen turn off or when sleep need password to show user session screen (user desktop).

Comment: @JosephSible no drive encryption was not enabled but why i should do that? I think its a simple thing that system should ask for password after wake from hibernate and i think user does not do anything to get this feature.

Comment: Because if you don't have encryption enabled, it's trivial to bypass all local password prompts, so much so that you may as well not have them.

Comment: Hibernate and Suspend arent "safe" operations by their nature. One of them creates a "dump" of your memory into swap, and the other, keeps your computer with the bare minimum of energy to keep things in RAM. Not even encrypting your driver is a security panacea here and having a solution that works with FDE and Hibernate will take you time into customization - Take a look at these 2 links - https://askubuntu.com/q/95625/494660 - https://superuser.com/q/648333/210242 - I think your question is way too broad to be answered.